# How to break string into N 80 character lines?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to display a welcome message in the start of my script:

```
echo "Running $0 $@"
```

But `$@` might be very long. How can I break this line into multiple up-to-80 character lines?

Comment: BTW, you should use `$@` only as `"$@"`. For other use cases, use`$*`. The explanation is in the bash manage. So in your case, `echo "blah $*"`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `fold`.

```
echo "Running $0 $@" | fold -sw 80
```

`-s` wraps on spaces.
`-w 80` sets width to 80 columns.

Comment: Note that 80 is the default value for width so `w 80` can be left out (but it doesn't hurt to be specific of course).

Answer (score 3):

Of course `fold` is the best option, but you can also achieve this with `grep` or `sed`:

```bsh
echo "Running $0 $@" | grep -o '.\{80\}[^ ]* '
#or
echo "Running $0 $@" | sed -E 's/(.{80}[^ ]*) /\1\n/g'
```

Note, this will break at 80 chars + 1 word, so it might not be suitable for you.

Answer (score 3):

Although others mentioned tools that break the lines just before the word that hits the 80-character limit, there is also another tool that tries to not break the lines just before end of after start of a sentence and does other things for better readability. Its usage is similar:

```
echo "…" | fmt -w 80
```

The `-w` option specifies the maximum width of the text, but the text will use only 93 percent of the line (this can be overridden by using `-g`).

This is how `fold` formats the text:

```
Although others mentioned tools that break the lines just before the word that 
hits the 80-character limit, there is also another tool that tries to not break 
the lines just before end of after start of a sentence and does other things 
for better readability. Its usage is similar:

    echo "…" | fmt -w 80

The `-w` option specifies the maximum width of the text, but the text will use 
only 93 percent of the line (this can be overridden by using `-g`).

The long sentence that hits the 80 character column count is this one and here.
```

And this is output from `fmt`:

```
Although others mentioned tools that break the lines just before the word
that hits the 80-character limit, there is also another tool that tries
to not break the lines just before end of after start of a sentence and
does other things for better readability. Its usage is similar:

    echo "…" | fmt -w 80

The `-w` option specifies the maximum width of the text, but the text will
use only 93 percent of the line (this can be overridden by using `-g`).

The long sentence that hits the 80 character column count is this one
and here.
```

You can notice that the last (exactly 80-char long) get wrapped, but not at column 75 (the 93 % of 80), but a word before it, because we do not want to have one word on the line alone (in printed text etc.).